# Gmail corporate domain alias

Tags: gmail, alias

I have a google corporate account, I have already set up 5 other domain alias for my email accounts.  I already own all these domains, and all of the domains were registered through the same hosting company.

for example:

john@domain1.com
john@domain2.com
john@domain3.com
john@domain4.com
john@domain5.com

But I am trying to add another alias and google tells me that the domain is already in use, which is not possible because I own this domain already.  Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know how I would go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the previous owner was still verified as the owner. I had to contact google support and they sent me the instructions to verify us as the owners of the domain.